# checking virtual environment modules

Tags: python, module, virtualenv, lxml

So I am following this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-1-project-setup/) and I am about to give up since i am working on a windows machine and I am pulling my hair out finding equivalencies.
I have a virtual environment, but when I try to run my code it dosent appear to be finding the local dependancies!!

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Vince\skellys\Flask_skelly\venv> python Bartender_no_ui.py
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Bartender_no_ui.py", line 7, in <module>
import lxml                        
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

How can i check if the dependencies are there and how do i make sure my code is running from venv?? Am I just to much of a noob to be trying this tutorial anyway??
maybe relevant details- I had to use Conda rather than pip to install lxml, because pip couldnt get the dependencies of libxml2 and libxslt, but I get no module error for the other modules that I installed in the venv using pip as well

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
pip freeze
```

That should show you what modules you have installed in your virtualenv as long as you have it active.

Seeing as how you are working on windows I'd check out this [site](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/) Its what I followed when I first got started.

Haven't used Conda much myself so not familiar with how it works but I'm guessing that won't install to your virtualenv. If you download lxml from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) you should be able to install it into your virtualenv on windows.

Comment: This question has developed a bit - pip and pip freeze are working fine, but now when I try to install lxml i get an error saying i havent installed 2 dependencies, but also an error message saying those dependincies (libxml2 and libxslt) cannont be found....

Comment: Are you using the package from that site? As I just setup a sample virtualenv and installed it with no problem

Comment: apparently im not .... how do you sepcify the site from which you are installing? sorry ive been a coder or like 4 months :/

Comment: No worries had those problems as well. If you download from the site I have listed you should then be able to do `pip install <path to downloaded.whl file>` with your virtualenv active and it will install it there.

Answer (score 0):

its not the best solution but I figured out a hack around - I copied lxml from my c:\anaconda\pkgs folder. Code appears to be running fine. figures.